# Frame and fixedSize modifier

Tags: swiftui, layout

What does `fixedSize` do?

Does it just fix all layout behaviours to be equal to `idealWidth`/`idealHeight`?

If so, can we say that

```
frame(width: w, height:h)
```

is equivalent to

```
frame(minWidth: w, idealWidth:w, maxWidth: w, minWidth: h, idealWidth:h, maxWidth: h)
```

or not?

Comment: Have you read the SwiftUI documentation on these properties?

Comment: @TylerH
yep, what should I understood from them?

Comment: Some of the issue may be a language barrier. You left out a critical word, but I assume meant "what does `fixedSize` do. I edited your question in an attempt to clarify it; please make further edits as necessary if I misunderstood what you are trying to ask.

Comment: @TylerH Yep, thanks for editing, it's all good now =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally a `View` is constrained by the space proposed to it by its parent, which is called `proposedSize`.

Some views use the whole proposed space (`Color`, `Rectangle`). Others will take their `idealSize`, restricted by this `proposedSize` (something like `min(idealWidth, proposedWidth)`).

The best example is the `Text` view.
Let's take a `Text` view of 97 points wide :
when the parent view offers it 150 points wide, it uses only 97 points.

[image: first example]

When the parent view offers it only 50 points wide, it uses only 50 points wide (and goes over several lines).

[image: second example]

If we use the `fixedSize` modifier, we make a *counter-proposal* as Apple says. That is to say that we propose to the view to use its `idealWidth` rather than the `proposedWidth`.

Applied to a Text view, this means that it will not be constrained by the width offered by the parent view, and therefore will not span several lines.

[image: third example]

Applied to a `Rectangle`, it becomes more surprising: its `idealWidth` seems to be 10 points...

[image]

Applied to a `UIKit` view (wrapped with `UIViewRepresentable`), the idealWidth will be equivalent to `intrinsincContentSize.width`.

```
struct MyViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MyUIView {
        let view = MyUIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .orange
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MyUIView, context: Context) { }
    
    class MyUIView: UIView {
        override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
            CGSize(width: 70, height: 70)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: last example]